# Initial paper of Gel'fand on Generalized Random Processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, generalized-functions

The theory of generalized stochastic processes was introduced independently in the 50's by Ito* and Gel'fand in a short paper. The latter then developed his theory more extensively in the fourth tome of his work on Generalized functions**.

I am looking for the initial short paper of Gel'fand, in Russian, with the following reference:

*I. M. Gelfand,Generalized random processes, Doklady Akademii Nauk SSSR100
(1955), no. 5, 853–856, in Russian.*

I couln't find it on the web. According to [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/generalized-random-processes/oclc/23670034&referer=brief_results), it is in the MIT, too far for me. Does anybody have another solution to obtain this historical paper?

*K. Itô, Stationary random distributions, Kyoto Journal of Mathematics 28
(1954), no. 3, 209–223.

**I. M. Gelfand and N. Ya. Vilenkin, Generalized functions. Vol. 4. Applications of
harmonic analysis, Academic press, New York, USA, 1964.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A translation of it appears on pp. 529-533 of Gel'fand's *Collected Papers*, Volume III, Springer 1989, which should be available in a library closer to you...

Comment: Effectively, it was closer! Now I have the paper. Thanks a lot for the reference.

Answer (score 6):

In general, Soviet Doklady for those years are not available on the web.
They were not translated into English at that time, and the Russian original has not been digitalized
(unlike ALMOST ALL other Russian journals which are available free on mathnet.ru
(one has to know some Russian to use this site)).

However, if you have an access to a university library, even one which does not have
Doklady, you can use Interlibrary Loan. Just ask the librarian. I worked in several countries, and everywhere
this option was avialable in research libraries. In any case, much more libraries have old Russian Doklady than Collected papers of Gelfand.

Comment: Though it is a pity that the collected works of Gelfand are not more widely available...

Comment: Just checked on Amazon. $270 per volume.